# Android app won't open

Tags: java, android, animation, emulation

This is my code for my splash screen:

```
public class SplashScreenPear extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pear);
    startAnimating();}
private void startAnimating(){
  ImageView pearfade = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pearish);
  Animation pearfadeact = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
 pearfade.startAnimation(pearfadeact);}

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
   ImageView pearfade = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pearish);
  pearfade.clearAnimation(); 

  Animation pearfadeact = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);

  pearfadeact.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {


         public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                 // The animation has ended, transition to the Main Menu screen
                 startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenPear.this, Unicorn.class));
                 SplashScreenPear.this.finish();
             }

             public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
             }

             public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
             }
         });
         }
     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();

                      startAnimating();
     }
```

Unfortunately the application won't open, and it won't progress from the splash screen. I don't believe there is a problem with the emulator that I'm using so it must be something in this code that is preventing it from fully running. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: This question is very generic, it is unclear whether the code will not compile, is throwing an error or is not behaving as you expect.  Tell us what your expected results are and what your actual results are along with any logcat output that might be relevant.

Comment: Post your logcat logs, with the exact exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnResume() will be called automatically after onCreate() anyway, so you shouldn't need to put a call to startAnimating() in onCreate.
The line SplashScreenPear.this.finish(); might not be called- I'm not 100% certain on this though.

I can't tell you more without knowing what you mean by it won't run- won't compile? Gives a run time exception? Just a black screen?

Edit: You are also adding the list ener during the onPause method- which isn't going to be called...
This code will be less buggy and more efficient:

```
package com.unicorn.test.whee;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class SplashScreenPear extends Activity {

ImageView pearfade;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pear);
    ImageView pearfade = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pearish);
}

private void startAnimating(){

 Animation pearfadeact = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
 pearfadeact.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
             // The animation has ended, transition to the Main Menu screen
             startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenPear.this, Unicorn.class));
             SplashScreenPear.this.finish();
         }

         public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
         }

         public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
         }
     });
     pearfade.startAnimation(pearfadeact);

}

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  pearfade.clearAnimation(); 
 }
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     startAnimating();
 }
```

Comment: You can find out what might be causing a crash by looking at the details of the Exception in LogCat.